# how to interpret outpuf of gpg --list-keys --with-colons --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint

Tags: gpg

For example if you take this output from https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS, you can see several records dispatched on each line.

```bsh
$ gpg --with-colons --list-keys \
      --with-fingerprint --with-fingerprint wk@gnupg.org
pub:f:1024:17:6C7EE1B8621CC013:899817715:1055898235::m:::scESC:
fpr:::::::::ECAF7590EB3443B5C7CF3ACB6C7EE1B8621CC013:
uid:f::::::::Werner Koch <wk@g10code.com>:
uid:f::::::::Werner Koch <wk@gnupg.org>:
sub:f:1536:16:06AD222CADF6A6E1:919537416:1036177416:::::e:
fpr:::::::::CF8BCC4B18DE08FCD8A1615906AD222CADF6A6E1:
sub:r:1536:20:5CE086B5B5A18FF4:899817788:1025961788:::::esc:
fpr:::::::::AB059359A3B81F410FCFF97F5CE086B5B5A18FF4:
```

My problem is with the fpr (fingerprint records), there are three in the example.
Which one is what ? The doc doesn't clarify this.
The goal behind this, is to do a thorough clean up using the following commands :

```bsh
yourKeyName="myname <myname@myemail.com>"
# delete private keys
for fpr in $(gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons --fingerprint "${yourKeyName}" 2>/dev/null | awk -F: '/^fpr:/ { print $10 }')
do
    gpg --batch --delete-secret-keys --yes "$fpr"
done
# delete public keys
for fpr in $(gpg --list-keys --with-colons --fingerprint "${yourKeyName}" 2>/dev/null | awk -F: '/^fpr:/ { print $10 }')
do
    gpg --batch --delete-keys --yes "$fpr"
done
```

But which record to use and why are there thee fpr records ?

NB : my version of gpg

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19                                                                                                                                                             
libgcrypt 1.8.5
```

Comment: http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/sipb/user/kolya/gpg/gnupg-1.2.1/doc/DETAILS
"The double --with-fingerprint prints the fingerprint for the subkeys
too, "
Key/subkey (pub/sub) . and the next fpr record is for that key/subkey.

Comment: @K-att
Alright about the third fpr record which is related to the subkey.
But what about the second fpr record ? what is its semantics ?
From my tests, the first fpr record allows to delete the key.

Comment: pub, after fpr, sub, after fpr another sub, after fpr....

Comment: Thx K-att; I think I need to understand better the notion of subkey ot fully understand this output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "grep" to get the gpg key fingerprint values?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/743982/how-to-use-grep-to-get-the-gpg-key-fingerprint-values)

Answer (score 2):

> But which record to use and why are there thee fpr records ?

Each *subkey* also has its own fingerprint. Deleting the primary key (1st fingerprint) will automatically delete "the whole thing" (all subkeys and userids), but specifying a subkey fingerprint (2nd or 3rd) will only delete that one subkey.

As you're searching for keys by name, have you tried just *giving the name* to `--delete-key`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about subkeys. My goal is to raz all the data for a given name.

Comment: (continuing last comment) 
So I'll just need to catch the first fingerprint to delete all.
Gnu gpg is confusing, at least the man page. 
I hopped to avoid going through a whole tuto on the subject ...