# How to use "grep" to get the gpg key fingerprint values?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, pgp

If the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` is

```
pub   rsa3072 2023-01-13 [SC] [expires: 2025-01-12]
  D8524A558964E86Cxxxx93111270xxxxxxxx7A74
uid           [ultimate] demo(demo) <demo>
sub   rsa3072 2023-01-13 [E] [expires: 2025-01-12]
```

How can I grep only "D8524A558964E86Cxxxx93111270xxxxxxxx7A74" from the output? I am using Linux.

Comment: Why does your command output public keys when you explicitly ask for secret keys? When I run that command, I get two additional header lines you don't show (a file path and a line of dashes). Please update the question so that the command and the output that you say you see are correct. Also, mention what version of GnuPG you are using in case the output format has drastically changed between versions.

Answer (score 10):

From the man page:

> Never  use  the  output of this command in scripts or other programs.  The output is intended only for humans and its format is likely to change.  The --with-colons option emits the output in a stable, machine-parseable format, which is intended for use by scripts and other programs.

> **`--with-colons`**
> Print  key  listings  delimited  by colons. Note that the output will be encoded in UTF-8 regardless of any --display-charset setting. This format is useful when GnuPG is called
> from scripts and other programs as it is easily machine parsed. The details of this format are documented in the file ‘doc/DETAILS’, which is included in the GnuPG  source  distribution.

latest `doc/DETAILS` can be found [there](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/master/doc/DETAILS) for instance.

So:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons |
  awk -F: '$1 == "fpr" || $1 == "fp2" {print $10}'
```

Will print the fingerprints of all the keys listed there.

(`--keyid-format` is irrelevant, as that's the fingerprint you want).

Answer (score 1):

(This not very scientific but) one solution is execute the command and get the *big word* (be it 20 or more letters)

```
gpg...... | grep -Po '\w{20,}'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this potentially also match long names and other long strings in the output?

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, of course. But in many disposable situations this kind of dirty solutions (with the right `n`) are effective -- rarelly names and strings include words with 41 chars.

Comment: You could possibly tighten the expression a bit by using `[[:xdigit:]]` in place of `\w` (and then also change `-P` to the more portable `-E`). Also, aren't these fingerprints of a fixed length? You could use that length in `{...}` and then add `-w` to the `grep` command.

Answer (score 0):

If the value you are looking for, will always be on the second line, you can use something like that:

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long | sed '2!d' | tr -d " "
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting all occurrences of 40-char-long words containing only hexadecimal digits. Not very scientific either, but solves the problem.

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long \
| grep --only-matching --extended-regexp "[[:xdigit:]]{40}"
```